# Using JoddHttp put request to send JSON with the .body() corrupts Chinese text

Tags: java, jodd

My method is as follows：

```
public String submitMaterials(String url,JSONObject params) {
    return HttpRequest
        .create("put", url)
        .mediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        .body(params.toJSONString())
        .send()
        .bodyText();
}
```

The parameters I import：
[image]

[image]

Please help me，thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `mediaType`, it is just *a part* of ContentType, that does not set the encoding. So just use the `contentType()` instead:

```
return HttpRequest
        .create("put", url)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        .body(params.toJSONString())
        .send()
        .bodyText();
}
```

Note that you can use 2-argument version of `contentType` that sends media type and the content:

```
        .contentType("application/json", "UTF8")
```

Write version of `mediaType` method will be removed just not to confuse people. See the [javadoc](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/blob/master/jodd-http/src/main/java/jodd/http/HttpBase.java#L256) too.

Comment: Thank  you!   As you say, it's a success.

Answer (score 0):

i  do  this ,it's right:

```
public String submitMaterials(String url,JSONObject params) {
     return HttpRequest
           .create("put", url)
           .mediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
           .bodyText(params.toJSONString()，“UTF-8”)
           .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
           .send();
 }
```

Comment: Dont need to use both mediaType and ContentType.